# print dictonary list stepping 3 by 3

Tags: python

I had to create a list comprehension of dictionaries that looks like the following:

> [ {0: [1, 2, 3]},  {1: [2, 3, 4]}, {2: [3, 4, 5]} … {100: [101, 102,
>   103]} ]

Created this with this piece of code:

> a=[{I-1:range(I,i+3) for I in range(1,101)]

Now were im stuck is printing each element in the list stepping 3 by 3 , i.e:

```
        {0: [1, 2, 3]}
        {3: [4, 5, 6]}
        {6: [7, 8, 9]}
        …
        {99: [100, 101, 102]}
```

Comment: One thing that I notice is that it would be easier if make one dictionary that holds everything instead of a list of dictionaries, unless you need 100 dictionaries.

Comment: @Anthony -- Or a list since the keys to the dict are just numbers starting from 0 . . . :-)

Comment: @mgilson, that would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use simple slicing:

```
a[::3]
```

will get you the list of every 3rd dict.  Just put it in a loop to print it:

```
for dct in a[::3]:
    print(dct)
```

demo:

```
>>> a=[{I-1:range(I,I+3)} for I in range(1,101)]
>>> for dct in a[::3]:
...   print(dct)
... 
{0: [1, 2, 3]}
{3: [4, 5, 6]}
{6: [7, 8, 9]}
{9: [10, 11, 12]}
{12: [13, 14, 15]}
{15: [16, 17, 18]}
{18: [19, 20, 21]}
{21: [22, 23, 24]}
{24: [25, 26, 27]}
{27: [28, 29, 30]}
{30: [31, 32, 33]}
{33: [34, 35, 36]}
{36: [37, 38, 39]}
{39: [40, 41, 42]}
{42: [43, 44, 45]}
{45: [46, 47, 48]}
{48: [49, 50, 51]}
{51: [52, 53, 54]}
{54: [55, 56, 57]}
{57: [58, 59, 60]}
{60: [61, 62, 63]}
{63: [64, 65, 66]}
{66: [67, 68, 69]}
{69: [70, 71, 72]}
{72: [73, 74, 75]}
{75: [76, 77, 78]}
{78: [79, 80, 81]}
{81: [82, 83, 84]}
{84: [85, 86, 87]}
{87: [88, 89, 90]}
{90: [91, 92, 93]}
{93: [94, 95, 96]}
{96: [97, 98, 99]}
{99: [100, 101, 102]}
```